# Select query with IN range and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Right now this is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblChatMessage  
WHERE groupID IN (456, 789) 
LIMIT 20
```

the limit needs to be in every part of the IN range (so 20 of the 456 and 20 of the 789). How can I do this? The range is variable to the case. It could be 2 or 100.

Comment: `UNION` of two separate queries

Comment: The range of the groupID's is variable. In this example, I use 2 but it could perfectly be 100.

Comment: Then build this *unionized*  query dynamically.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM tblChatMessage WHERE groupID = 456 LIMIT 20)
union all
(SELECT * FROM tblChatMessage WHERE groupID = 789 LIMIT 20)
```